# Changing positive/negative signs in a linear equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been doing a problem set and ended up with this:
$$1 = 8×50 - 19×21$$
Now I have to change the sign of $21$ from a negative to a positive. In order to do that, I have to subtract $8$ by $21$ and $-19$ by $50$. Afterwards, I get
$$1 = -13×50 + 31×21$$
I just do not understand how changing each value by $21$ and $50$ gives the same answer. Is anyone able to go into more detail on this?

Comment: What do you mean with 'subtract 8 by 21'? 8-21? or 21-8? or something else?

Comment: I think you meant _from_ instead of _by_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $ax+by=1,$ then also $a(x+b)+b(y-a)=1.$ To see that multiply the second one out and cancel something.